# Jenkins Blue Ocean Installation Warning

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have spent a significant amount of time configuring numerous jobs, complex multi jobs, and now even a series of pipelines within the Jenkins CI suite. I have backed up all of my job configurations (config.xml files).

My question relates to the Blue Ocean plugin[s]. When viewed in the plugin manager, the Blue Ocean plugin has the following warning:

> Warning: This plugin requires dependent plugins be upgraded and at least one of these dependent plugins claims to use a different settings format than the installed version. Jobs using that plugin may need to be reconfigured, and/or you may not be able to cleanly revert to the prior version without manually restoring old settings. Consult the plugin release notes for details.

I am just wondering if there will be a significant reconfiguration process I will have to go through after installing this plugin. Will it change any of my existing jobs/multi-jobs/pipelines?

[image: Blue Ocean Warnings]

Comment: Does it say which plugin?

Comment: Attached screenshot to answer showing the first 5 with the warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have performed the upgrade and verified all of my existing jobs (including multi-jobs) remain unchanged/unaffected. The Blue Ocean plugins do not seem to alter existing job configurations at all.

For anyone who is apprehensive to install Blue Ocean because of these warnings, do not worry; it appears to be a harmless installation.

Comment: Blue Ocean itself will not modify any of the jobs or their underlying data. It does depend on minimum versions of certain plugins  (mainly the pipeline or "workflow" plugins and some SCM plugins) that probably triggered those warnings. Thanks for clarifying here.